# ManyToMany Hibernate annotation

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, annotations, many-to-many

I have this relationship in my database:

[image]

And I want to be able to create an order, that contains more products (as well more instances of the same product). Nevertheless I am able to have just one row in the `order_has_product` table for every single `order_id`. Moreover, I tried to load the data via lazyloading, but it won't work and it makes the whole app to run really slowly. Here are definitions of the relationship in my entities:

OrderEntity:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@Cascade({org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.ALL})
@JoinTable(name = "order_has_product",
        joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "order_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
        inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "product_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private List<ProductEntity> products;
```

ProductEntity:

```
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "products")
private List<OrderEntity> orders;
```

Any idea how to fix lazyloading and to make it possible to have more products in order?

Comment: Why does your join table have an id property and why is ProductEntity.orders eager fetched? There is a good reason why it is lazy fetched by default.

Comment: Agreed. Change this Fetchtype to 'Lazy', this might improve performance. Does it throw an exception or what is happening?

Comment: That was the first thing I've tried-to set everything to Fetchtype.LAZY, but it doesn't work.. It doesn't throw any exception...it just downloads all data at once

Comment: @Gimby I've go there ID just because I like to have some identifier in every table...and I don't expect that this could cause the problems